# how to remove specifically matched elements using xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

**html:**

```
<div class="ls-col" id="ls-row-2-col-2">
    <div class="ls-col-body" id="ls-gen79493564-ls-col-body">
        <div class="ls-row" id="ls-row-2-col-2-row-1">
            <div class="ls-fxr" id="ls-gen79493565-ls-fxr">
                <div class="ls-area" id="ls-row-2-col-2-row-1-area-1">
                    <div class="ls-area-body" id="ls-gen79493566-ls-area-body">
                        <div class="grid-container">
                            <div class="grid-100">
                                <div class="intro_content slide_content grid-40">
                                    <div class="current"></div>
                                    <div class="next"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

**expected:**

```
<div class="ls-col">       
    <div class="ls-row">              
        <div class="ls-area">                        
            <div class="grid-container">
                <div class="grid-100">
                    <div class="intro_content slide_content grid-40">
                        <div class="current"></div>
                        <div class="next"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to remove div's which contain following classes

1. ls-col-body
2. ls-area-body
3. ls-row-body
4. ls-fxr
5. just remove all the id attributes which starts with ls- not the div just id attribute.

I tried matching this way. but not understanding how to remove it

```
   <xsl:template match="div[contains(@class,'ls-col-body')]">      
      <xsl:apply-templates select="container"/> <!-- some template -->
   </xsl:template>
```

Comment: "*I want to remove div's ... just remove all the id attributes ... not the div just id attribute.*" That's confusing. Why don't you post the expected result of your example input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this XSLT:

First template is used to copy nodes and attributes. second one to remove divs with particular values and third to omit id attributes starting with ls-

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div[@class='ls-col-body' or @class='ls-area-body' or @class='ls-row-body']">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@id[starts-with(.,'ls-')]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I think you'd missed one div with class=ls-fxr in your output.

Comment: can you explain a bit...what does this do ?
`<xsl:apply-templates />`

Comment: apply-templates will apply templates for the children of the context node. In the above case, any existing or built-in template will be applied for the child nodes of the context "div". Hence, continuing processing of children of div and not just stopping at there.